# V11.0 Facebook Graph API - since / until not populating entire date range

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm doing the following request in the Facebook Graph API explorer:

```
   url = f'https://graph.facebook.com/{page_id}/posts?since=2021-02-02&until=2021-02-10&
    fields=id,created_time, from,shares,comments.limit(0).summary(true),
    insights.metric(post_impressions_paid,post_impressions_paid_unique).period(lifetime),
    attachments{title, unshimmed_url}&access_token={page_access_token}'
```

but when I look at the created_time it only shows from  `"created_time":"2021-02-06T20:00:13+0000"` to `"created_time":"2021-02-09T23:30:04+0000"`

Comment: How many posts are you expecting? Are you sure you don't need to paginate?

Comment: @CBroe I expected there to be a post for each day, I checked and we do have posts created for each day of that range.